# Vanguard fund, Roth IRA, and 1099

Tags: united-states, taxes, mutual-funds, roth-ira, vanguard

About a week ago, I opened a Roth-IRA and purchased  a Vanguard life strategy fund (VASGX), made the contribution for 2013 Tax Year. I should get q 1099, correct? How long does this normally take?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you shouldn't get 1099. 1099 is for distributions, not contributions. You should get form 5498, in May.

Comment: So.. there's nothing to report to Uncle Sam for 2013 taxes (in regards to opening this fund)?

Comment: @SoilSciGuy not that I know of.